# Why does .step_by() expect a usize?

Tags: rust

I am trying to implement a function with nested for loops. I am having trouble with the `.step_by()` function, however.
Here is my code:

```
fn get_prime_factors_below(n: i32) -> HashMap<i32, Vec<i32>> {
    for i in 2..n / 2 + 1 {
        for j in (i * 2..n).step_by(i) {
            //
        }
    }

    return factors;
}
```

This returns the following error when I try to compile it:

```
 for j in (i * 2..n).step_by(i) {
                     ------- ^ expected `usize`, found `i32`
                     |
                     arguments to this function are incorrect
```

Why does `.step_by()` expect a `usize` and doesn't work with an `i32`?

Comment: What do you make of the error message?

Comment: @JohnKugelman I'm not sure I understand the error message, as the same code works fine outside of the function.

Comment: Hint: `as usize`. This is a reasonable thing to do if `i` is *always* non-negative. Since this depends on `n` being non-negative, you may want to screen for that case. Lazy solution: `n: usize`.

Comment: It's saying that `i` is an `i32`, but you need to pass `step_by` a `usize` instead. When you're debugging try to figure out the precise thing you don't understand. (I know that's not always possible, but often it is.) Some more specific questions could be: "Why does `step_by` expect a `usize`?" or "What's the difference between `i32` and `usize`?" or "How can I convert `i` into a `usize`?"

Comment: @JohnKugelman Gotcha, I'll edit the question.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. That small edit makes this quite an interesting question, IMO. Why indeed does `step_by` take `usize` and not the `Iterator::Item` type? The cat in my lap is preventing me from typing a proper answer but I expect you'll get a good one from others.

Comment: @JohnKugelman `Iterator::Item` is unrelated. It could be `String`.

Comment: Yes, I understand, that's part of the answer I would write. At first blush one might think `step_by` would take `i32` since we have an `Iterator<Item = i32>`, but it doesn't for several reasons, one of which you allude to. That's how I imagine tackling the question, at least.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `usize` makes sense when you are, through some manner, performing an index lookup. If you were to try and perform an index lookup with an unsigned integer that couldn't represent numbers smaller than `usize` (e.g. `u8`) you potentially wouldn't be able to address the whole container - remember that on any system Rust targets, `usize` is the pointer-sized unsigned integer.

The largest step you might want to make is a `usize`-sized step over an iterator which occupies all your memory. If we used a larger size than this, the largest step would step into memory our system can't represent. If we used a size smaller than this, we wouldn't be able to make the biggest possible step at all!

Using this same logic, by using `usize`, your code can be compiled for 32 bit and 64 bit systems without having to make any changes. In this way, `usize` is 'correct', any other integer type can create problems for you later on.